# remove pie chart slices labels in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, charts, pie-chart

I am using Asp.Net Mvc 3 to create a pie chart using Chart Helper, but I have a problem, I don´t know how to remove the labels that are on the slices, what I get is like this:

[image]

I want to remove the names that are labels in the chart.

Answer (score 1):

Apply theme to your chart if you haven't. In theme add following line-

```
<Series>
  <Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Pie" CustomProperties="PieLabelStyle=Disabled">
  </Series>
</Series>
```

This will hide labels appearing on the pie chart.